# Varint encode/decode issue with number > 2^31-1

Tags: c++

The code bellow works as expected with numbers <= 2^31-1 but produces wrong (way to large) result on numbers > 2^31-1. This is unexpected since since I never used uint32_t.

```
void encodeVarint(uint64_t value, uint8_t* output, uint8_t &outputSize)
{
    outputSize = 0;

    while (value > 127)
    {
        output[outputSize] = ((uint8_t)(value & 127)) | 128;
        value >>= 7;
        outputSize++;
    }

    output[outputSize++] = ((uint8_t)value) & 127;
}

uint64_t decodeVarint(uint8_t* input, uint8_t &inputSize)
{
    uint64_t ret = 0;
    inputSize = 0;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        ret |= (input[i] & 127) << (7 * i);
        inputSize++;

        if(!(input[i] & 128))
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(input[i] & 127)` should have type `int` and it may be 32-bit long.

Try

`ret |= (uint64_t)(input[i] & 127) << (7 * i);`

instead of

`ret |= (input[i] & 127) << (7 * i);`

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing it out! It works! Do you see anything else dangerous with my code?

Comment: You don't do any error checking in your code and it may be dangerous. I think this code is good for valid inputs.